# Double inheritance and polymorphism. How to have two separated members from one base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I need to use polymorphism to `do_something` on objects inherited from **BaseA** but my **D** objects should have two seperated members named `enabled`. I mean that `D::changeEnabled()` should change `SecondBaseB::BaseA::enabled = 0` and `SecondBaseC::BaseA::enabled = 0` and these two members should be separate (different). Is it possible to have polymorphism and not using virtual inheritance? Without `virtual public BaseA` i have ambigous error. But with virtual inheritance i have only one `BaseA::enabled`.

```
//
// main.cpp
//
#include <iostream>
#include "D.h";

void do_something(BaseA& o) {
    o.changeEnabled();
}

int main() {
  SecondBaseB b;
  SecondBaseC c;
    D d;
  do_something(b);
  do_something(c);
    do_something(d);
    std::cout « "Hello, World!" « std::endl;
    return 0;
}

//
// BaseA.h
//
class BaseA {
protected:
    bool enabled;
public:
    BaseA();
    virtual void changeEnabled() = 0;
};

//
// BaseA.cpp
//
#include "BaseA.h"

BaseA::BaseA() : enabled(true) {

}

//
// SecondBaseB.h
//
class SecondBaseB : virtual public BaseA{
public:
    virtual void changeEnabled();
};

//
// SecondBaseB.cpp
//
#include "SecondBaseB.h"

void SecondBaseB::changeEnabled() {
    enabled = !enabled;
}

//
// SecondBaseC.h
//
#include "BaseA.h"

class SecondBaseC : virtual public BaseA {
public:
    virtual void changeEnabled();
};

//
// SecondBaseC.cpp
//
#include "SecondBaseC.h"

void SecondBaseC::changeEnabled() {
    enabled = !enabled;
}

//
// D.h
//
#include "SecondBaseB.h"
#include "SecondBaseC.h"

class D : public SecondBaseB, public SecondBaseC{
public:
    virtual void changeEnabled();
};
```

In a different words. I have following scenario: base abstract class *Car* with `engine` member. I create *DieselCar* and *ElectricCar* which are inherited from *Car*. Then i want to create *HybridCar* which would inherited from *DieselCar* and *ElectricCar* and have two different `engines`. With using virtual inheritance there's only one engine. Without using `virtual` I cannot accomplish following:

```
void testDrive(Car* c) {
c->drive();
c->drive();
}

HybridCar h;
ElectricCar e;

testDrive(&h);
testDrive(&e)
```

Comment: Templates and [`std::enable_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) are a great tool for such cases.

Comment: What do you expect `do_something(d)` to do if there are two different `enabled` members?

Comment: Using a `virtual` base class says that you only want one base object of that type. Since you want two, don't use virtual inheritance. `D` will have to understand that there are two bases and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about your **Car** scenario, to have multiple information about **Car** subclass that have more than an **Engine** the code can be refactored using Composite Pattern, in this way:

- *Car **owns** an Engine*
- ***Engine*** is an interface or abstract class that acts like the **Component**
- ***Leaf*** is a concrete subclass of Engine that has a meaning like **ElectricEngine**, **DieselEngine**, etc...
- ***PowerUnit*** acts like the **Composite** and so, it **owns** references to some **Engine**s

[image]

Then every costructor of every concrete subclass of **Car** initialize the attribute

```
Engine* engine;
```

declared in the abstract class **Car**, in correct way.
For example,

```
 ElectricCar(){
     //other members
     engine=new ElectricEngine();
 }

 DieselCar(){
    //other members
    engine=new DieselCar();
 }

 HybridCar(){
   //hybrid car is composed by an electric and diesel engine
   engine=new PowerUnit(Engine* engines);
 }
```

If the abstract class looks like

```
 class Engine{
    private bool enabled;
    public:
       virtual Engine* getEngine(int number=0){ return this};
       virtual final bool isEnabled(){return this->enabled};
       virtual final void setEnabled(bool value){ this->enabled=value;}
    }
```

the `getEngine()` method must be implemented in his true function in subclass **PowerUnit**.

```
class PowerUnit{
     private:
        Engine*[] engines;
     public:
       PowerUnit(){
         engines[0]=new ElectricCar();
         engines[1]=new DieselCar();
       }
       getEngine(int number){ return engines[number];}
   }
```

Finally, if the client (**Car**) wants to check in an hybrid car which engine is active(or both), it can use the pointer **engine** as in the following way that check if the first engine is active:

```
engine->getEngines(0)->isEnabled;
```